# Windows Phone 8.1 DatePicker Style

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm developing an application and I want to use a control which does the same job as the "DatePicker"

Any help is much appreciated, I know its name is Looping List in Telerik Controls but I don't have a subscription for Telerik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the below sample for Windows Phone 7, hope this would work for WP 8.1

http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-loopingselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api

Hope this could help you

It is about Looping Selector

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, thank you billion times! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Windows Phone Toolkit

In project of your solution Go to References>Manage Nuget Packages>Online> Search for Phone.Controls>
Install Windows Phone Toolkit

In Xaml

**Add the xmlns namespace**

xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"

**and Add the control in Grid**

```
<toolkit:DatePicker Header="Select Date"/>
```

**Sample**

```
  <phone:PhoneApplicationPage
        x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
        xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
        FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
        Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
        xmlns:toolkit="clr-    namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
        SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
        shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
                <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                //Add the Control
                <toolkit:DatePicker Header="Select Date"/>

            </Grid>
       </Grid>

    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but this is not what I want, I meant that I want to manipulate a datepicker with other data not with date and time :)

Comment: Sorry i misread the question

Comment: Its okay mate thanks a lot for your contribution :)